# AWS S3 Gradle dependency line

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gradle

Is there any way to add AWS S3 compile line to `build.gradle` to load jar files to Android project?
I can add them to libs folder after downloading full zip package from Amazon. But I want to do it using dependency.

I've tried something like this, but have no luck.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk:+'
}
```

The only solution had result was using java sdk, but I want to use new Android lib.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:+'
}
```

Can I find and read more info about how to build compile line, where to find this line in Maven repo? I need S3 and Core libs for my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is found in the documentation:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Android SDK does support Maven/Gradle.

Please see this blog post
https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx33541C1DGXVQ2/AWS-Mobile-SDK-for-Android-Maven-Support
Or just search the Maven repo for "android" http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws

Answer (score -1):

The Android SDK libraries are not available in Maven Central therefore you cannot bring them in as a remote dependency. Apparently this is something the Amazon AWS team is [looking into](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=574439).

Comment: It looks like they are available now http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx33541C1DGXVQ2/AWS-Mobile-SDK-for-Android-Maven-Support